# modify polygon in android google map api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I started Google map in android few days age. I am doing some basic things like set marker on tap, draw line between two marker etc.

Here users can draw polygon with tapping on the device. Now i want to edit the shape. I goggled it but didn't find any helpful solution for android.

I found some resource on google map java script API like [user-editable-shapes in javascript](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/user-editable-shapes)

I want to do the same in android. How to **Edit** or **Modify** polygon in **Google Map Android API**

It will be helpful if u provide some resource.

Comment: I know there's an `editable:true` property you can set in v3 (Javascript), but I don't think such functionality exists for v2 (Android). It's a bit hacky, but I think what you'd have to do is set up a listener for when you click on a point on the polygon's perimeter, then edit that point and redraw the polygon while you drag.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you have to replace all the points at once with setPoints on the polygon object.

[https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon.html#setPoints(java.util.List)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon.html#setPoints(java.util.List%3Ccom.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng%3E))

I'm currently trying to do the same thing in Xamarin. I mock up an edit mode when the user clicks on the polygon by changing its stroke color and then adding custom markers to each vertex. I'm holding a selected vertex which will move to the user's next click on the map and update the polygon.

Comment: its not working for me. is it working for you? for me its adding extra point randomly in polygon

Comment: I'm no longer using the google maps apis in my project, so unfortunately I can't really comment on how this all works anymore.